# Issue with filling autocompletetextview

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();           
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {      
  while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
          c_Name.add(name);
    }
 }
 name_Val = (String[]) c_Name.toArray(new String[c_Name.size()]);
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name_Val); 
 txtPhoneName.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As I am debugging I follow the code till `txtPhoneName.setAdapter(adapter)` and the `ArrayAdapter adapter` is filled with the contacts starting `{null, "Name1", "Name2"...}`.

When it comes to `autocompletetextView` it doesn't show anything, if instead I use fixed `String [] d={"NAME1","Name2","name3"}` it binds them just fine.

Comment: Hi Tony, I improved your question and the code you provided. Please spend more time in formatting and description the next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Than it has to be the null, change this and it should work, before c_Name.add(name); 
check if name is not null !

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted can't be working or at least you didn't post the relevant stuff.

`name_Val` is never used anywhere. Also make sure that your contacts doesn't start with a `null` entry as it might result in not showing anything...

Comment: I am using name_Val here
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name_Val); 
at the end

Comment: ok, I didn't see that, sorry. Have you made sure that your first entry is not null? Does this fix it?

Comment: well in my phone book i have no entry null ( of maybe the first entry that i my number )so therefore i don;t know how it gets that null at the beginning

Comment: I love being voted down without a comment saying whats wrong. Thanks! Nice done!